# How to fix an inaccessible variable in idris2?

Tags: idris, idris2

I am having trouble to make a short idris2 code from the summer school course [SPLV20](https://github.com/edwinb/SPLV20/blob/master/TinyIdris-v2/src/Text/Token.idr) work. The error is at the last line:

```
module Text.Token

%default total

||| For a type `kind`, specify a way of converting the recognised
||| string into a value. ...

public export
interface TokenKind (k : Type) where
  ||| The type that a token of this kind converts to.
  TokType : k -> Type

  ||| Convert a recognised string into a value. The type is determined
  ||| by the kind of token.
  tokValue : (kind : k) -> String -> TokType kind

||| A token of a particular kind and the text that was recognised.
public export
record Token k where
  constructor Tok
  kind : k
  text : String

||| Get the value of a `Token k`. The resulting type depends upon
||| the kind of token.
public export
value : TokenKind k => (t : Token k) -> TokType (kind t)
value (Tok k x) = tokValue k x
```

The error says: `While processing right hand side of value. {k:978} is not accessible in this context.`

My current understanding is that `k` is a quantity 0 variable in the `value` function, so it cannot be used in the function body `tokValue k x`.

I tried to fix this by adding `k` as an implicit argument, `value : TokenKind k => {k : Type} -> (t : Token k) -> TokType (kind t)`.

But now the types are wrong, and the system complains that:

> While processing type of value. Can't find an implementation for
> TokenKind k.

I am only learning idris2 (0.60), and it's  beyond me to fix this error.

**My questions are:**

1. Where in this file is the implementation of the `TokenKind` interface for the `Token` type? It seems to be hidden/implied and therefore I don't know how to provide the missing implementation.
2. How to fix the error about `k` being not accessible?

Comment: this is probably a duplicate qustion, but I'm not going to look. Try `{k : Type} -> TokenKind k =>`. `TokenKind k => {k : Type} ->` defines two distinct `k`s